# Highlight area of ggplot based on user input shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, ggplot2, shiny, spatial

I have a basketball half court created in ggplot that I've embedded inside a sidebarPanel in Shiny and I would like to highlight "zones" of the court based on user input. I was thinking I could use something along the lines of renderUI coupled with geom_rect() to get what I want, but nothing I've tried seems to work. Can anyone help with this?

I've attached an image link that is hopefully helpful in supplementing my explanation above along with current code.

Thank you!

[Court Zones Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlWdJ.png)

```
teams <- c("Hawks","Celtics","Nets","Hornets","Bulls","Cavaliers",
       "Mavericks","Nuggets","Pistons","Warriors","Rockets","Pacers",
       "Clippers","Lakers","Grizzlies","Heat","Bucks","Timberwolves",
       "Pelicans","Knicks","Thunder","Magic","76ers","Suns","Trail 
        Blazers", "Kings","Spurs","Raptors","Jazz","Wizards")

server <- function(input, output) {

output$half_court <- renderPlot({

ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = court[court$side==1,], aes(x = x, y = y, 
group = group), col = "gray") +
coord_equal() +
xlim(-2,50) +
ylim(-2,50) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 25, 50)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 12.5, 25, 37.5, 50)) +
xlab("") + ylab("") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) +
geom_rect(aes_string(xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = 37.6, ymax = 47), fill 
= "yellow", alpha = 0.20) +
geom_rect(aes_string(xmin = 40, xmax = 50, ymin = 0, ymax = 9.4), fill 
= "green", alpha = 0.20)
}, bg = "transparent")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel(title=div(img(src="primary.png", height = 50, width = 
50),strong("Database"))),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("season", "Season",c("","2016","2015","2014")),
  selectInput("team", "Team 1",c("",teams)),
  selectInput("team", "Team 2",c("",teams)),
  selectInput("pass", "Pass Location",c("",1:25)),
  selectInput("poss", "Possession Location",c("",1:25)),
  plotOutput(outputId = "half_court")
  ),
mainPanel()
)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: pls share `teams` so that the code is reproducible,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist - Thank you for your help! I've added `teams` for reproducibility. Your code below does the trick!

Comment: @BigDataScientist - By any chance is there a way to make the squares extend all the way to the corners of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base plot you could have a transparent plot (`renderPlot({...}, bg="transparent")`), add transparent rectangles (`rect(..., col = rgb(0, 50, 255, 50, maxColorValue = 256))`) to it and add the picture as a background via CSS (`HTML("#plot{background:url(https://...)}))`).

[image]

For a sample app, see below:

```
bckpic <- "https://thedatagame.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/nba_court.jpg"

pos <- function(x, y){
  xx <- x1 <- (x - 1)*5 + c(0, 5)
  yy <- 25 - ((y - 1)*5 + c(0, 5))
  return(c(xx[1], yy[2], xx[2], yy[1]))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type='text/css', HTML("#plot{background:url(https://thedatagame.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/nba_court.jpg);
                                    background-size: 200px 200px;
                                    background-repeat: no-repeat;}")),
  selectInput("pass", "Pass Location", 1:25),
  selectInput("possess", "Possession Location", 1:25, 25),
  uiOutput("style"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(0,0,0,0))
    plot(0, 0, ylim = c(0,25), xlim = c(0, 25), type='p', yaxt = "n", 
         xaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
    nr <- as.numeric(input$pass)
    posi <- pos(ifelse(nr%%5 > 0, nr%%5, 5),ceiling(nr/5))
    rect(posi[1], posi[2], posi[3], posi[4], col = rgb(0, 50, 255, 50, maxColorValue = 256))

    nr <- as.numeric(input$possess)
    posi <- pos(ifelse(nr%%5 > 0, nr%%5, 5),ceiling(nr/5))
    rect(posi[1], posi[2], posi[3], posi[4], col = rgb(255, 50, 0, 50, maxColorValue = 256))

  }, bg="transparent", width = 200, height = 200)
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nevermind on the question above. Figured it out by simply changing the `ylim` and `xlim` numbers inside `plot()`. Thanks again for the really straightforward answer, it simplified my overall code considerably.